# iOS: Xcode projects relativity

Tags: xcode

I often encounter several Xcode projects from the web that have another Xcode project within them.

What I mean is that there are another Xcode project included from another.
What does it do and how do it work? Just curiosity...

Answer (score 0):

Projects or Xcode workspaces can include additional projects. Sometimes it is better to split parts of develompmet into different projects and not always is the result of the project an application. I can be a custom library you may use in the other project.

So if you make changes to the library only you don't have to compile the complete application. Just rebuild the library and link it to your application in the other project.